# Manim is not correctly drawing tikzpictures

Tags: python, manim

I'm very very new to coding and am mostly trying to learn on my own. I'm starting to pick up the basics of manim, but am still having difficulties with troubleshooting. I've been trying to get manim to draw tikz diagrams and I've spent hours digging through what seemed like similar issues. I finally got it to draw the diagram, but it's all messed up and I can't find any solutions online.

I'm trying to do a tree diagram. It should look like this (from LaTeX):

[image]

The code I put in for manim is:

```
from manimlib.imports import * 

class TikzMobject(TextMobject):
    CONFIG = {
    "stroke_width": 3,
    "fill_opacity": 0,
    "stroke_opacity": 1,
    }

    class Tree(Scene):
        def construct(self):
        
            
            TreeDiagram = TikzMobject(r"""
            \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=5em,level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},level 3/.style={sibling distance=1cm},every node/.style={shape=rectangle,rounded corners,draw,align=center}]]
            \node {Start}
            child { node {$s_1$} 
            child { node {$p_1$}
            child { node{$f_1$}}
            child { node{$f_2$}}}
            child { node {$p_2$}
            child { node{$f_1$}}
            child { node{$f_2$}}}}
            child { node {$s_2$} 
            child { node {$p_1$}
            child { node {$f_1$}}
            child { node {$f_2$}}}
            child { node {$p_2$}
            child { node {$f_1$}}
            child { node {$f_2$}}}}
            child { node {$s_3$}
            child { node {$p_1$}
            child { node {$f_1$}}
            child { node {$f_2$}}}
            child { node {$p_2$}
            child { node {$f_1$}}
            child { node {$f_2$}}}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            """)
            TreeDiagram.scale(0.3)
            TreeDiagram.rotate(TAU/2)
    
            self.play(FadeIn(TreeDiagram))
```

But what it produces is this:

[image]

Please help! I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

That's because Manim removes styles from SVGs (manim compiles the .tex file into dvi, then transforms the dvi to svg), so you can't depend on LaTeX styles for Manim, you'll have to do it by hand or create a class on your own.